# On-Prem SharePoint 2013-Exchange 2013 Task Sync not working

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-server, tasks, exchange-server

How do I troubleshoot the task sync? I followed instructions and I believe the EWS API is installed OK and the trust relationship is there. Both SharePoint and Exchange are on-prem 2013 with the latest CUs.

I get:

> "We weren't able to sync your tasks. This could be because your
> mailbox is on an Exchange server that isn't supported for syncing
> tasks. Please contact your admin..."

There is a correlation ID but I honestly do not know what you can do with that. I assume it is in some log file?

Autodiscover Command

> Name                           : EXCHANGE13
> AutoDiscoverServiceInternalUri : https://exchange.xyz.com/Autodiscover/Autodiscover.xml

From ULS:

> 04/09/2018 13:55:58.68 w3wp.exe (0x1F04)   0x06B8  SharePoint Server Search    Exchange Integration    ah9c2   Medium  AutodiscoverLocalException: Autodiscover blocked a potentially insecure redirection to https://exchange.xyz.com/autodiscover/autodiscover.xml. To allow Autodiscover to follow the redirection, use the AutodiscoverUrl(string, AutodiscoverRedirectionUrlValidationCallback) overload. 0adf5b9e-fc44-a017-22e1-e9a3888bda7d
>
> 04/09/2018 13:55:58.68 w3wp.exe (0x1F04)   0x06B8  SharePoint Server Search    Exchange Integration    aiwxi   Medium  SearchServiceApplication::ExchangeAdapter::SharePoint CorrelationId:; Exchange Request Id:; Diagnostic Info:    0adf5b9e-fc44-a017-22e1-e9a3888bda7d
>
> 04/09/2018 13:55:58.68 w3wp.exe (0x1F04)   0x06B8  SharePoint Server Search    Exchange Integration    ai1pi   Medium  Autodiscover Diagnostics EWS Client Version: 15.00.0516.014 0adf5b9e-fc44-a017-22e1-e9a3888bda7d

Using:

> Get-ClientAccessServer |fl identity,autodiscoverserviceinternaluri

The output is now:

> Identity                       : EXCHANGE13
> AutoDiscoverServiceInternalUri : https://autodiscover.xyz.com/Autodiscover/Autodiscover.xml

I have a host name of autodiscover pointed to the IP of the server. The cert is OK as it is a wildcard.

Comment: The correlation ID will be in the [SharePoint ULS logs](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/SharePoint/administration/view-diagnostic-logs). However, I would suggest not using Exchange Task sync. This functionality no longer exists in SharePoint Server 2016 or SharePoint Online.

Comment: Thank you. I found a log viewer that helped tremendously. I know the sync is gone in 2016 but they boss wants this wrong. I need to get him to discuss our path forward since MS really wants you to use one of the other cloud apps for items like this, hence the removal from 2016.

Comment: 04/09/2018 10:45:10.26 w3wp.exe (0x1F04) 0x1B00 SharePoint Server Search Exchange Integration ah9c2 Medium AutodiscoverLocalException: Autodiscover blocked a potentially insecure redirection to https://exchange.xyz.com/autodiscover/autodiscover.xml. To allow Autodiscover to follow the redirection, use the AutodiscoverUrl(string, AutodiscoverRedirectionUrlValidationCallback) overload. 1fd45b9e-1c36-a017-22e1-e524a3b28891

I do not think I can modify the code in the EWS API to solve this? Can I? What is the solution?

Comment: Is your autodiscover domain the same as your other Exchange domains? Is your autodiscover URL running over HTTPS?

Comment: It is HTTPS. autodiscover is working for Outlook just fine. It points to exchange.xyz.com. Our local domain is xyz.local but I do not believe I am using that anywhere.

Comment: Yes, but for SharePoint autodiscover needs to be on it's own domain. It expects autodiscover.example.com.

Comment: I do have autodiscover.xyz.com setup in DNS too. It is an A record as I thought the CNAME might be causing this. autodiscover.xyz.com points to the IP of the Exchange server. Is that what you mean?

Comment: Add the output of `Get-ClientAccessService | select AutoDiscoverServiceInternalUri` to your original post. Grab a ULS log, filtering the category for 'Exchange'. Trigger a task sync. Post the ULS log here.

Comment: I have added the info above.

Comment: I'd strongly suggest adjusting your autodiscover record to https://autodiscover.xyz.com/autodiscover/autodiscover.xml and retry. As I said earlier, the EWS code for task sync/picture import expects it. I suspect your CNAME is the issue based on the info you've provided.

Comment: Sorry, not trying to be dense. Please see the edits at the bottom.

Comment: Your AutoDiscoverServiceInternalUri must be pointing at autodiscover.xyz..... Simply having the CNAME isn't sufficient. I would perform this change after hours and test.

Comment: The AutoDiscoverServiceInternalUri is now indeed autodiscover.xyz.com... IIS was reset on Exchange. And then in DNS I have a Host (A) pointing to the IP of the exchange server. I still get the error.

Answer (score 0):

1.Make sure User profile synchronization server is up and running .

2.Make sure you have Work Management service application running for your SharePoint Farm .

3.You also need have Search service Application

Follow the article to configure sync task from [here](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/SharePoint/administration/configure-exchange-task-synchronization) .

Additional ,You need to check and verify the AD domain is added as an accepted domain in Exchange .

https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/9fe2e7e4-1a8d-4249-979b-30574c043dbb/sharepoint-2013-exchange-2013-task-sync-error?forum=sharepointgeneral

Comment: I found the issue but have no idea what to do.

AutodiscoverLocalException: Autodiscover blocked a potentially insecure redirection to https://exchange.xyz.com/autodiscover/autodiscover.xml. To allow Autodiscover to follow the redirection, use the AutodiscoverUrl(string, AutodiscoverRedirectionUrlValidationCallback) overload.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I had turned off TLS 1.0 and that was causing this issue.